# Is this Unwise Use of the 'this' Keyword?

Tags: java, variables, this, scope

Basically I have a class called WarriorSkills and I want to update the damage done of a skill based on the Warrior objects Weapon stats. The only way I could figure out to get a reference to the object of the warrior class to alter the stats of the Warriors skill based on the warriors weapon object (damage and strength), was to use an argument of the warrior class for the method getRoughSkillDamageModified() within the class WarriorSkills.

First Class

```
public class WarriorSkills extends Skills {
private int rageCost;
private double damageModified;

public void getRoughSkillDamageModified(Warrior plc) //By Armour/Weapon stats
{
    damageModified = plc.getWeapon().getAverageDamage() + plc.getStrength();
}

public void updateStats()
{
    this.setStrength(this.getStrength() + this.warriorWeapon.getBonusStrength());
    this.skills.getRoughSkillDamageModified(this);
}
```

Second Class

```
public class Warrior extends StrengthUser {

private String className = "Warrior";
private StrengthWeapon warriorWeapon;
private WarriorSkills skills;

public Warrior(Warrior originalObject)
{
    super(originalObject);
}

public Warrior(int stam, int health, int resi, int str, int rage, StrengthWeapon 
warrWep, WarriorSkills warSkill)
{
    super(stam, health, resi, str);
    this.skills = warSkill;
    this.warriorWeapon = warrWep;
}

public String getClassName()
{
    return className;
}

public void updateStats()
{
    this.setStrength(this.getStrength() + this.warriorWeapon.getBonusStrength());
    this.skills.getRoughSkillDamageModified(this);
}


public StrengthWeapon getWeapon()
{
   return this.warriorWeapon;
}

public WarriorSkills warriorSkills()
{
    return this.skills;
}
```

}

But as you can see in order to invoke this method (within the Warrior class) I have to use
'this' representing the Warrior class both as the calling object and being passed as the argument. Now this use of the 'this' keyword seems kind of odd to me, but does seem to work. Is it avoided by convention or anything, or does it have any potential issues. My book doesnt seem to have informed me yet and I always like to experiment.

Updated with full class definitions. Note Warrior class inherits from a StrengthUser class which inherits from a PlayerClass class. And WarriorSkill inherits from a Skill class.
Edit: Damn forgot to omit the fiddling code =/
Bleh updated again,Note to Self: dont fiddle with code between asking questions and posting full classes. The method call that the question was about in the first place was missing lol. It is there again now.

Comment: why use this? If the function are within the class, no need

Comment: As explained. getRoughSkillDamageModifier() is in a WarriorSkills class. updateStats() is in the Warrior class. The getRoughSkill... method requires a reference to Warriors.Weapon to update the skill damage with stats (Weapon dmg etc) from the Warriors.Weapon

Comment: I think it would be very easy and hopefully there would be a lot of people helping if you could make it easier to understand. Try renaming the class name to easier one like A, B etc. And similar getters and setters

Comment: Which class(es) are each of the two methods shown members of? Which class contains an instance of the other? I don't feel like the example is fully illustrating the issue.

Comment: The Warrior class contains an instance of the WarriorSkills class and Weapon class, the WarriorSkills class has no instances of other classes

Comment: This is how it makes sense to do it to me, as it is ultimately the Warrior that can use a weapon and can use a skill

Comment: @FinalFind could you remove some of the methods that aren't required from your examples, and possibly break the method signatures down so there is no horizontal scrolling? Your question will receive a lot more attention :)

Comment: Also note the Skills class from which WarriorSkills inherits cotains the skills baseDamage instance variable (skill damage before updateStats() but as modification involves strength the modifiedDamage instance variable is in the WarriorSkills subclass

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All of the places where you use `this.` in the example code are *unnecessary*.  However, it is up to you to decide whether it is "wise" or not.

It is a matter of opinion.

Some people think that using `this.` improves readability makes it explicit that the field or method you are using / calling is a member of the target class.  I don't think that it helps, except possibly for Java beginners.

However, there are cases where it is *necessary* to qualify with `this`; e.g.

```
public class Example {
    private int field;
    public void setField(int field) {
        this.field = field;  // 'this' is required here ...
    }
}
```

---

If you are asking about ... `skills.getRoughSkillDamageModified(this)`, there is absolutely nothing "unwise" about passing the current object's reference as a parameter to some other method or constructor.

Comment: Aye, you are right about that, but it is not what the question is about =P. I just got into the habbit while learning as in my opinion it made the code make more sense. The specific question about the getRoughSkillDamageModified(Warrior plc) and the call to it this.skills.getRoughSkillDamageModified(this); I am aware that the this. is not needed at the start, but it doesnt mean that the calling object is not also the paramater

Comment: Thanks that is what I was after hearing about. I figured it must be a conventional thing to do, as it worked, and was the only possible way I could create the updateStats() method how I wanted (well without reconfiguring the code significantly and changing my approach). But sometimes you never know.

Answer (score 1):

Why pass the object at all if you only need two values? Passing the object means that the `WarriorSkills` class ends up knowing more about the inner workings of the `Warrior` class than it really needs to.

Instead, in the `Warrior` class (omitting unnecessary uses of `this`):

```
skills.getRoughSkillDamageModified(getWeapon().getAverageDamage(), getStrength());
```

and in the `WarriorSkills` class (assuming both parameters are doubles):

```
public void getRoughSkillDamageModified(double avgDamage, double strength)
{
    damageModified = avgDamage + strength;
}
```

Also, a method name like `getFoo` would conventionally return the value of `foo`. It would be better to name this method `setRoughSkillDamageModified` instead

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to undertstand my code and point this out =). It is indeed an effective solution (though there may end up being more values required as the project gets larger). Also you are right that the word setRoughSkillDamageModified would make more sense as I am setting the value not simply returning it.

Comment: I have now called it with skills.setRoughSkillDamageModified(warriorWeapon.getAverageDamage(), getStrength());